# BalloonItemizedOverlay dragging

Tags: android, dictionary

I use BalloonItemizedOverlay to display pins on a map. The user is allowed to drag it and when dragging is finished, I replace it on the new position on the map. All this is working as expected, but the only thing I have no clue on how to do is: **How can I have that pin to be updated on the map during the dragging phase?** On IOS and javascript this happens automatically without adding code, but not so on android. What is the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please move pin/marker instead of ballon view.

Comment: That's what I do. The Balloon is not visible and dragging is successful. The only thing is that pin remains on initial position during dragging phase.

Comment: use new set location, and clear all sites from overlay, and add new site.

Comment: that's what I do when I get MotionEvent.ACTION_UP . Are you suggesting to do that when I get a MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ?

Comment: I am on returning "true": if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && inDrag!=null) { result=true; } else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) { result=true; }
return(result || super.onTouchEvent(event, map));

Comment: I only create this once in oncreate() in my Activity  and dont change them programatically. Only user can drag

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6816/discussion-between-jitendra-sharma-and-michaelsmith)